# Ubuntu 14.04 mod_ssl not available

Tags: 14.04, apache2, openssl, mod-ssl

When I try to install **mod_ssl** it say **Unable to locate package mod_ssl**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get install mod_ssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mod_ssl
```

Comment: [`mod_ssl.so` is in `apache2-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mod_ssl.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), and if you installed that, you don't need to install anything more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you installed apache2, mod_ssl should be available at /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so. Simply run `a2enmod ssl` and then `service apache2 restart` to enable it.

Comment: thanks this helped me to solve but need to do with sudo